# How do I fix the WSOD in phpMyAdmin and Drupal in chrooted Apache?

Tags: apache-http-server, phpmyadmin, chroot, drupal

When I attempt to run phpMyAdmin (both 3.5.5 and 4.0.4.2) or Drupal (7.22) in chrooted Apache (2.2.3), I get the WSOD (White Screen Of Death; a.k.a. a blank page).  I have tried with both mod_chroot (0.5, apache 2.2.3) and ModSecurity.  The HTTP response codes are 500, but there are no errors in any of the logs.

I have verified that sessions and MySQL work when mod_chroot is enabled. I have also verified that both phpMyAdmin and Drupal work when mod_chroot is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After ignoring phpMyAdmin and moving on to Drupal, I ran across the same issue.  After a quick search, I found this:

http://www.redbarontech.com/content/drupal-running-chroot

After copying the "timezone files" to the chroot jail, as described in the article, both Drupal and phpMyAdmin started working. I have updated the question to make it a bit more generic.

**Edit:**

Here's the relevant command from the article:

```
cp -fR /usr/share/zoneinfo/* /jail/usr/share/zoneinfo/
```

I just adapted it for my own setup.

Comment: It would be nice if you could copy the relevant pieces from the linked article into your answer (and leave the link for reference).

Comment: @OliverSalzburg There isn't exactly a wealth of information there, but I added the relevant command to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort :) If you would like to have your bounty refunded (because you found the solution yourself anyway), let me know. Of course, there's nothing wrong with letting the bounty stand in case someone might come up with a solution you like better (if that's possible).

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Thanks, but I suppose that it is _possible_ that someone could provide a cleaner solution, though I am satisfied with this solution and suspect that's the best it will get with a chroot environment.